# Como hacer que un servlet espere a ver si ha subido el archivo antes de redirrecciona

Tags: java, servlets, filesystem

Quería pediros si se os ocurre como hacer que tras subir una fotografía a una carpeta del servidor, desde la misma servlet que sube la imagen se compruebe que la imagen esta totalmente subida antes de redirigir a otra pagina.

Todo viene porque en la siguiente pagina se mostrar la imagen, y me ocurre que a unas veces que antes de que haya totalmente subido la imagen al servidor el servlet a ha redirigido a la otra pagina y la imagen no se puede todavía mostrar.

A mi se me ha ocurrido con la clase file, comprobar que hasta que no este totalmente subido en este caso las dos fotos no rediriga a otra pagina, y aunque los comprueba, no se me ocurre exactamente como validarlo. Me explico, con un if va a pasar el condicionante viendo que todavia no esta cargada la imagen y ahi se para la servlet sin redirigir a la otra pagina, siendo no lo esperado. 
Y con un bucle while no me ha funcionado, entre otras he puesto el bucle while vacio, que no es lo correcto, pero además no funciona.

Pego un poco el codigo por si ayuda más a orientar lo que pediría:

Código:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {

        /**
* Aqui estamos confirmando el MultipartFormDataRequest y le indicamos que recoja todo lo que
* nos esta mandando el index.
*/
        MultipartFormDataRequest mrequest = new MultipartFormDataRequest(request);


        String nombre = mrequest.getParameter("nombre");
        String descripcion = mrequest.getParameter("descripcion");




        //mirar video de youtube en carpeta JAVA y comentar codigo


        JDBC helper = new JDBC();

        String consultaSQL = "SELECT RutaCarpetaLocal FROM path where NombreCarpeta='Fotos1'";
        ResultSet   rs = helper.Select(consultaSQL);
        /*en este caso en el servidor hay que poner la ruta especifica hasta la carpeta local en el servidor
                     * la de fotos actuales y la otra carpeta de fotos antiguas
                 al estilo: C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\BackEnd\Images\Fotos1
                 para que la libreria uploadBean pueda subir hasta esa carpeta.
                 IMPORTANTE PONERLA SIN LA ULTIMA BARRA DEL ULTIMO DIRECTORIO, SINO UPLOADBEAN DARA ERROR*/


        String RutaCarpetaLocal1 = "";
        String RutaCarpetaLocal2 = "";

        if (rs.next()) {
            RutaCarpetaLocal1 = rs.getString("RutaCarpetaLocal");
        }

        String consultaSQL2 = "SELECT RutaCarpetaLocal FROM path where NombreCarpeta='Fotos2'";
        ResultSet  rs2 = helper.Select(consultaSQL2);



        if (rs2.next()) {
            RutaCarpetaLocal2 = rs2.getString("RutaCarpetaLocal");
        }




        UploadBean upBean = null;

        /**
             * Usamos un HashTable que es un directorio, se podria usar como una tabla pequeña.
             * mrequest.getFiles() = recoger todos los archivos de la imagen.
             */
        Hashtable files = mrequest.getFiles();
        /**
     * si UploadBean sirve para que podamos subir al servidor objetos, entonces 
     * UploadFile sirve para poder subir Archivos al servidor.
     * 
     * En este caso, al usar el comando GET, le estamos diciendo a lo que
     * tenga dentro de sus parentecis se vaya al objeto file, pero como 
     * el objeto que obtenemos es de tipo Hashtable le colocamos un cast
     * para que podamos recuperar la informacion si problemas.
     */
        UploadFile file = (UploadFile) files.get("Foto1");


        String name1 = file.getFileName();


        UploadFile file2 = (UploadFile) files.get("Foto2");


        String name2 = file2.getFileName();


        /**
        * Empezamos a utilizar el UploadBean y colocamos la opcion setFolderstore
        * para poder indicar en que direcion vamos a guarda todo archivo que nos mande.
        */
        upBean = new UploadBean();

        upBean.setFolderstore(RutaCarpetaLocal1);

        /**
     * Con el Store le decimos al MultipartFormRequest que obtenta tambien la imagen.
     */
        upBean.store(mrequest, "Foto1");


        /**
        * Empezamos a utilizar el UploadBean y colocamos la opcion setFolderstore
        * para poder indicar en que direcion vamos a guarda todo archivo que nos mande.
        */
        upBean = new UploadBean();

        upBean.setFolderstore(RutaCarpetaLocal2);

        /**
                 * Con el Store le decimos al MultipartFormRequest que obtenga tambien la imagen.
                 */
        upBean.store(mrequest, "Foto2");





        int IdUsuario = 1;


        String usuario = "admin";
        Connection Conexion;
        Conexion = helper.Conexion();


        PreparedStatement misentencia;
        misentencia = Conexion.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO imagenes VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        Conexion.setAutoCommit(false);

        misentencia.setInt(1, 0);
        misentencia.setString(2, nombre);
        misentencia.setString(3, descripcion);

        misentencia.setString(4, name1);
        misentencia.setString(5, name2);
        misentencia.setInt(6, IdUsuario);
        misentencia.setString(7, usuario);


        misentencia.executeUpdate();
        Conexion.commit();
        Conexion.close();

        response.sendRedirect("tablaImagenes.jsp");


    } catch(Exception ex){

        out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano por las ideas!

Saludos

Comment: Deberías poner el código completo del servlet a donde se sube la foto, porque el escenario que comentas es raro: el servlet no debería redirigir a ningún sitio hasta que el fichero está totalmente guardado, son tareas que se hacen de modo secuencial. Creo que el problema es distinto al que planteas

Comment: Entonces sería un problema de HTML y DOM?. Me explico de la servlet redirige a otro archivo que va mostrar esa imagen en una tabla coon otros datos mas sobre esa imagen, y es ahí donde a veces falla y no se muestra la imagen hasta que se recarga la pagina una ó varias veces.De todas formas veo que la servlet ya esta redirigiendo antes de ver al imagen subida en la carpeta...he pegado el codigo en mi mensaje original..Gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: Repito: deberías darle a [edit] y añadir el código, no podemos ayudarte sin ver los detalles

Comment: Pues ya esta le codigo desde hace rato...gracias.

Comment: Sigo sin entender para que este hombre me hace pegar todo el codigo de la servlet, cuando en mi mensaje original habia pegado el trozo de codigo donde estaba por resolver el problema...me pide que pegue todo el codigo, para despues ni molestarse en responder...es cierto que soy yo el que estoy pidiendo ayuda, y lo estoy agradeciendo constantemente.....pero molestarse en cumplir las peticiones de alguien para que despues ni se moleste en contestar, no lo veo correcto....

Comment: Para reproducir el problema o tratar de ejecutar *mentalmente* el código y ver el flujo, necesito ver todo el método

Comment: Por lo que veo el framework que usas es antiguo (no tiene genéricos, por ejemplo), pero encontré la documentación [aquí](http://www.javazoom.net/jzservlets/uploadbean/documentation/api/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

La [documentación](http://www.javazoom.net/jzservlets/uploadbean/documentation/api/index.html) es muy pobre, pero no parece que los métodos para guardar ficheros sean asíncronos: en principio yo esperaría que cuando

```
upBean.store(mrequest, "Foto2");
```

se ha completado, el fichero esté ya guardado. Podrías hacer una comprobación con algo como

```
File f= new File(<path>);
while (!f.exists() || f.length() < file2.getFileSize()) {
    // no está grabado
    this.wait(1000); //esperar un segundo
}
```

Pero realmente me extrañaría que fuese este el origen del problema

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, muy amable. Voy a probar con la solución que has dado a ver si fuera solo eso. A veces todo va como la seda, y otras veces le da por fallar que hay que refrescar el navegador una ó dos veces para que se muestre la imagen recién subida. Puede que sea más algo de la vista más del controlador pero no se me ocurre el qué. Probare con tu solución dada. De nuevo gracias por la aportación, saludos

Comment: Confirmado sigue fallando. Por donde será por el lado de la vista, ahi solo hago que introducir por DOM cada imagen en una etiqueta < img> e incluirla en otra etiqueta <a> y esta a la vez en una etiqueta <p>.Demasida etiqueta?

Comment: Sospecho que el servidor web no se entera de que ese nuevo archivo existe todo lo rápido que a ti te gustaría... comprueba la configuración de tu Apache, Nginx o lo que uses para servir contenido estático y si la actualización es configurable